# Sei Sei Sei chant

Tags: culture, phrase-requests

I just finished the manga, [Goodnight Punpun Vol. 1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1421586207) and I noticed several occasions within the work where a character crossed their arms and chanted "Sei".  Could someone tell me the meaning of this gesture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean this?

[image]
(taken from the [sample here](http://sokuyomi.jp/product/oyasumipun_001/CO/1/))

This strange gesture and chant is not something widely shared in the Japanese culture.

From what I can tell from the sample, this gesture is intended to be meaningless and puzzling at first sight. It feels just like other surrealistic expressions found throughout the sample. Maybe this is going to be proven meaningful somewhere after vol. 1. Maybe it will be meaningless forever.

[This tweet](https://twitter.com/comanchieeeeeee/status/78799100476272641) says it's a religion(?) found only in this manga. I think it's reasonable, but I couldn't confirm it.

Comment: That's exactly it, thank you for your response.